# Is it possible to extend definition in CueLang

Tags: schema, cuelang

Is it possible to extend Definition?

For example, lets say that we want to have Connection definition like this

```
Connection :: {
    protocol: "tcp" | "udp"
    port: int
    host: string
}
```

And we also want to have `SecureConnection` that has everything that `Connection` has, but we also like to add username and password. How to achieve this?

I can do it like this

```
Connection :: {
    protocol: "tcp" | "udp"
    port: int
    host: string
    ...
}

SecureConnection :: Connection & {
    username: string & >""
    password: string & >""
}
```

and it will work, but this also means, that this is not closed. Because of that three dots in `Connection` definition, we can add anything we want to secure connection

for example

```
tcp: SecureConnection & {
    protocol: "tcp"
    port: 8080
    host: "localhost"
    username: "guest"
    password: "guest"
    test: "testing"
    oneUnimportantVariable: "I am not important"
}
```

when I run `cue export myfile.cue` this will give me following JSON

```
{
    "tcp": {
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "port": 8080,
        "host": "localhost",
        "username": "guest",
        "password": "guest",
        "test": "testing",
        "oneUnimportantVariable": "I am not important"
    }
}
```

So, how to extend `Connection` definition and create `SecureConnection` definition, and not be able to specify any variable that isn't specify in this definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use definition embedding as below

```
Connection :: {
    protocol: "tcp" | "udp"
    port: int
    host: string
}

SecureConnection :: {
    Connection
    username: string & >""
    password: string & >""
}
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that. Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: It happens sometimes, I am also quite new to cuelang and just started playing with it.